# How to make PUT request RESTful?

Tags: rest, httphandler

With a single API resource `/`, we have written only one handler that process `GET` & `POST` request on API resource `/`

`POST` we use to create a resource in database, byt sending data in request body

`PUT` we use to update an existing resource in database

My understanding is, RESTful best practice says, a handler need to serve an API resource(say `/`) for all requests `GET`, `POST` & `PUT`

We want the same handler to process `PUT` request, but the API resource will be something like `/1234`, where `1234` is existing id

Technically, API resource `/1234` will also map to same handler that processes `/`, but,

---

From RESTful best practices, Does `/1234` need to be handled without passing id as part of API resource URI? something like below...

```
func  ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {


    if r.Method == http.MethodGet { // for API resource '/'
        p.getProducts(w, r)
        return
    }

    if r.Method == http.MethodPost { // for API resource '/'
        p.addProduct(w, r)
        return
    }

    if r.Method == http.MethodPut { // for API resource '/'
        p.updateProduct(w, r)
        return
    }

}

func updateProduct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var idString string

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    decoder.Decode(idString)

    id, err := findID(idString)
    // do whatever with id
}

func findID(str string) (int, error) {

    dfa := regexp.MustCompile(`/([0-9]+)`)
    matches := dfa.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) // returns [][]string
        
    idString := matches[0][1]
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(idString)
    
    return id, nil
}
```

Comment: REST doesn't offer guidance on the implementation of your request handlers; if you want "best practices" then you need to look for them elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood right you right.
You have two call which can be handle without `Id` for end point `/`.

One is `POST` when the back-end with generate you `Id` as a result.

Second is `GET` for all resources but this is up to you. Maybe because of secure reason you would not like to list all available resources.

One extra information is that `PUT` & 'POST' can use the same handler but logic in handler has to check if 'id' is provided and do extra more logic to create resource.

Comment: This is somehow redundant but you can and should. From RESTful perspective you are creating more consistence package of information - body. Important is that you add this to call end point `/id`

Comment: Oh got it... coarse grained resource (`/`) should be handled by a handler that internally invoke another handler that handles fine grained resource `/id`. Is that Correct? if yes, do we use middleware handler for such logic?

Comment: Your second comment is right. End point (`/`) please only for `GET` & 'POST' operation.

Comment: I have updated query with code changes, where `ServeHTTP` is single handler that takes care of `GET`, `PUT` & `POST` requests, for API resource `/`. Instead of redirecting from `/` to `/id` for `PUT` request, I have parsed the request body to retrieve `id`... Please comment on this

Comment: In my opinion you should not handle (`/`) by `PUT` without `id` in end point. Correct end point is (`/id`).

Comment: Can we chat in private room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223048/discussion-between-overexchange-and-hsd).